# R adding a row name (my index column) to the model results from predict

Tags: r, indexing, predict, write.table

I ran my training data through glmulti for best model fit and need to run the test data to get prediction results. I also need to include the unique ID for each record so I can match the results for using in downstream processes. I can get the results but don't know how to incorporate the alpha-numeric ID from the input dataset.

Run and print prediction

```
newnames <- c(
  'AADT',  
  'SPEEDLIM',
  'SpeedTrans')
new_all <- bind_rows(dat, test, absence_subset)

#Standardize variable ranges
new_all[,newnames] <- new_all[,newnames] %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, scale)

for (i in 1:ncol(new_all)) {
  if (is.numeric(new_all[,i])) {
    new_all[,i] <- c(new_all[,i])
  }
}

newdata <- new_all %>%
  select(all_of(newnames)) %>%
  droplevels()
newdf <- data.frame(newdata)
pred <- predict(m.glob2, newdf, type="response", full=T, )

newdata$fit <- pred
newdata$prob <- exp(pred)/(1+exp(pred))
outfile <- paste0(getwd(),"/Results/Predict_", animal, "_", area, ".csv")
write.table(newdata, file = outfile, sep = ",", row.names = F,  
            col.names = T, append = F)
```

The three variables in newnames are the variables used in the model. How do I incorporate the field "Event_ID" into the result table?

Answer (score 0):

That was too easy, sorry to bother. I think this project is causing burn-out. I just added the field name back into the file after the model ran. Posting below in case anyone else is looking for a quick anser.

```
newdata$fit <- pred
newdata$prob <- exp(pred)/(1+exp(pred))
newdata$Event_ID <- new_all$Event_ID
outfile <- paste0(getwd(),"/Results/Predict_", animal, "_", area, ".csv")
write.table(newdata, file = outfile, sep = ",", row.names = T, col.names = NA, append = F)
```